# How to merge two dates into a normal human readable date range

Tags: php, date, formatting

Say you have the following date range:

```
2010-04-10 - 2010-04-15
```

As a human, I might write this as `April 10 - 15, 2010`, or something like that. Not sure if there is a defined correct way of writing ranges like that, but anyways, if you were to do something like that, how would you do that? I'm not even sure where to begin...

I'd like to do this so that the date ranges potentially can be more compact, easier to read and also nicer looking.

Comment: Need a little bit more information. Are you just wanting to display the dates or manipulate them? Are you working with one date (the range) or two separate dates?  If it's two then I imagine it's just a case of formatting them to your desired taste and then simply printing them next to each other?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a case of formatting. Like `function format($date1, $date2)` or something.

Comment: Disappointed there's no "use this library" answer still :/

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a defined way to do, basically it's just logic. Try writing down in plain text what you think the rules should be with some examples. Like the example you gave is a good one. What if they're different months? What if it was April 2005 to April 2007, is that April 2005-2007?

Once you've got your plain text rules, the code will be easy. It's just about deciding on how you want to format it.

Comment: Absolutely right.  This is not a coding problem.  It's a specification problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample code that I used in my project. Hope it helps.

```
    $start_date = strtotime('2012-11-01');  
    $end_date = strtotime('2012-11-02');


    if ($end_date != '') {  
        $year1 = date('Y', $start_date);  
        $year2 = date('Y', $end_date);  
        $month1 = date('m', $start_date);  
        $month2 = date('m', $end_date);     

        if ($start_date < $end_date) {  
            if ($year1 != $year2) {  
                $holiday_date = date('F j, Y', $start_date) . ' to ' . date('F j, Y', $end_date);  
            }  
            else {  
                if ($month1 != $month2) {  
                          $holiday_date = date('F j', $start_date) . '&ndash;' . date('F j', $end_date) . ', '. date('Y', $end_date);  
                }  
                else {  
                          $holiday_date = date('F j', $start_date) . '&ndash;' . date('j', $end_date) . ', '. date('Y', $end_date);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        else {  
                $holiday_date = 'Invalid date range.';  
        }  
    }  
    else {  
            $holiday_date = date('F j, Y', $start_date);  
    }    
    echo $holiday_date;
```